# How to cast between to two similar composite types when altering the column type?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to change the type on a column from one composite type to another. The only difference between the two composite types is that the previous one used custom domains that prevented the attribute from being null. Upon running the command:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_address ALTER COLUMN target TYPE nullable_mailing_address USING target::nullable_mailing_address;
```

I recieve the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type mailing_address to nullable_mailing_address
```

What is the proper way to cast between two similar composite types? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompose and then compose the old type to the new one. If you just changed the field type, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_address
  ALTER COLUMN target TYPE nullable_mailing_address
  USING ((target).non_changed_field, (target).changed_field::new_type);
```

Almost same if you added/dropped field(s).

[Example](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b02bcf1a8fa8053e7367720f30f7b06b)

Comment: You are awesome! Worked, much appreciated.

Comment: How would you do this same thing if the column was an array of the composite type instead? Example schema from http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35479


```CREATE TYPE my_enum_type AS ENUM('e1', 'e2');

CREATE TYPE my_composite_type AS (
  my_enum my_enum_type
);

CREATE TABLE my_table (
  my_array_col my_composite_type[]
);```

Comment: @ZacharyKeener Your question actually is: How to convert value of type `A` to value of type `B`? Then use the solution in the `USING` clause. And your case is not related to the question asked here. So create new question to get an answer to it.

Comment: @hbd Did you manage to find a solution for casting between arrays of composite types?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Arrays of composite types called "tables" ;)

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Here is a very early morning now so quick solution without testing and explanation: `select array_agg(jsonb_populate_record(null::the_new_composite_type, to_jsonb(x))) from unnest(value_of_the_old_composite_type) as x;`